# Android | ANR - how to detect?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

Last version of my app has a lot of ANR issues on Google  Play Console. However , I have no idea how to detect it because unlike crash - there is no specific info what causes this error. I'm not able to reproduce it as well. I tried to set StrictMode but there is no info. Here's log from Google Play :

```
Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 15. Wait queue head age: 6275.4ms.)
com.app.activities.MainActivity

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x75575af0 self=0x7d33a14c00
  | sysTid=32404 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7db97df548
  | state=S schedstat=( 856817053 66517026 2057 ) utm=59 stm=26 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ff86f1000-0x7ff86f3000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000007cab0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 000000000002c8f0  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
  #02  pc 000000000005cd88  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244)
  #03  pc 000000000005db34  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+60)
  #04  pc 000000000005d988  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+176)
  #05  pc 00000000000519a0  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+72)
  #06  pc 0000000000136c34  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android_os_BinderProxy_transact(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+152)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:1129)
  at com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.isBillingSupported (IInAppBillingService.java:202)
  at com.mill.coders.purchases.payments.IabHelper$1.onServiceConnected (IabHelper.java:244)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1741)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1773)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:280)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6706)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

As you can see , if I'm not mistaken, suspicious is IabHelper class. It's very strange cause it is async method. Also - on the top of the screen you can see that log comes from Main Activity (right?) . IabHelper doesnt exist in MainActivity so WTF ? How can I test it ? :/ Here is how I use setUp method from IabHelper in different activity :

```
private fun goToOfferScreen() {
        offerScreenShown = true
        getItemPrice(item)
        animateView(whole_card, Techniques.SlideOutDown, 200)
        animateView(starImageView, Techniques.SlideOutDown, 200)
        ribbons.visibility = View.GONE
        levelUpTitle.visibility = View.GONE
        levelUpValue.visibility = View.GONE
        newLimitLabel.visibility = View.GONE
        newLimitValue.visibility = View.GONE
        coinBonusTitle.visibility = View.GONE
        coinBonusValue.visibility = View.GONE
        cashDiff.visibility = View.GONE
        delayAction({ showOfferScreen(item) }, 300)
        delayAction({ showButtonsWithDelay() }, 800)
    }
private fun getItemPrice(bankOfferItem: LevelUpOfferModel) {
        if (AppPreferences.isSamsungBuild) {

            val iapHelper = IapHelper.getInstance(context)
            iapHelper.setOperationMode(HelperDefine.OperationMode.OPERATION_MODE_TEST)
            iapHelper.getProductsDetails(bankOfferItem.bundle.name) { errorVo, arrayList ->
                errorVo?.let {
                    priceBtn.text = arrayList[0].itemPriceString
                }
            }
        } else {
            val sku = bankOfferItem.bundle.name
            val list = mutableListOf<String>()
            list.add(sku)
            purchaseHelper = InAppPurchaseRetry(InAppPurchase(a, Utilities.getApiKey()), 200, 5)
            purchaseHelper.setUp(context, object : InAppPurchase.Callback<IabResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(p0: IabResult?) {
                    purchaseHelper.getAllPurchases(list) { p0, p1 ->
                        try {
                            p1?.let {
                                inv = p1
                                if (it.hasDetails(sku)) {
                                    priceBtn.text = it.getSkuDetails(sku).price
                                } else
                                    priceBtn.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.resources.getString(R.string.alert_title_ooops), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onError(p0: Exception?) {
                    priceBtn.visibility = View.GONE
                }

            })
        }
    }
```